# How to prove this relationship between $\log\zeta(s)$ and prime counting function proposed in Riemann's paper?

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

This formula is considerably important in Riemann's paper "On the Number of Primes Less Than a Given Magnitude", giving the relationship between prime counting function and zeta function, but I do not get how the last line was derived:
\begin{align}
\log\zeta(s)&=-\sum_{p\ \rm prime} \log(1-p^s)\\
&=\sum_{p\ \rm prime}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}p^{-ns}\\
&=\sum_{p\ \rm prime}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}s\int_{p^n}^\infty x^{-s-1} dx\ \left(p^{-ns}=s\int_{p^n}^\infty x^{-s-1} dx\right)\\
&=s\int_1^\infty f(x)x^{-s-1}dx,\text{ where }f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\pi(x^{1/n})
\end{align}

Comment: why do you have an equality in parenthesis?

Comment: it is a substitution made to the previous line according to the identity

Comment: It's a trick allowing you to "extend your integral beginning from $1$ instead of $p^n$", I must go eating dinner, if it is still here after I'll answer you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is: you want your integral to go from $1$ instead of $p^n$, note that we can exchange the summing since these are positive, for fixed $n$:

$$\sum_p \int_{p^n}^\infty s x^{-s-1} dx =\sum_p \int_{1}^\infty s x^{-s-1} 1_{x\geqslant p^n}(x) dx =  \int_{1}^\infty s x^{-s-1} \sum_p 1_{x\geqslant p^n}(x) dx\\
= \int_{1}^\infty s x^{-s-1} \sum_p 1_{x^{1/n}\geqslant p}(x) dx
=\int_{1}^\infty s x^{-s-1}\pi(x^{1/n}) dx$$

With this you can easily deduce your computation

Comment: I do not quite get the notation $1_{x\geq p^n} (x)$ you are using here

Comment: It’s the characteristic function of the set $\{x, x \geq p^n\}$

Comment: So 1 if $x \geq p$, 0 otherwise

Comment: Ah I see how it goes, really elegant, appreciated!